# SDO in Mac OS X Yosemite

Tags: php, macos, osx-yosemite, sdo

Keep getting errors when installing SCA_SDO via PECL

```
   -MacBook-Pro:SCA_SDO-1.2.4 roland$ sudo pecl install SCA_SDO
downloading SCA_SDO-1.2.4.tgz ...
Starting to download SCA_SDO-1.2.4.tgz (576,531 bytes)
..............................................................................................done: 576,531 bytes
194 source files, building
running: phpize
Cannot find config.m4.
Make sure that you run '/usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.22/bin/phpize' in the top level source directory of the module

ERROR: `phpize' failed
```

then when i try manually downloading and installing i get the following

```
/Users/roland/Documents/sca_sdo/SCA_SDO-1.2.4/sdo.cpp:310:1: error: unknown type
      name 'function_entry'
function_entry sdo_model_propertyimpl_methods[] = {
^
/Users/roland/Documents/sca_sdo/SCA_SDO-1.2.4/sdo.cpp:325:8: warning: duplicate
      'static' declaration specifier [-Wduplicate-decl-specifier]
static ZEND_BEGIN_ARG_INFO_EX(arginfo_sdo_model_reflectiondataobject_exp...
       ^
/usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.22/include/php/Zend/zend_API.h:107:2: note: 
      expanded from macro 'ZEND_BEGIN_ARG_INFO_EX'
        static const zend_arg_info name[] = ...
        ^
/Users/roland/Documents/sca_sdo/SCA_SDO-1.2.4/sdo.cpp:330:1: error: unknown type
      name 'function_entry'
function_entry sdo_model_reflectiondataobject_methods[] = {
^
/Users/roland/Documents/sca_sdo/SCA_SDO-1.2.4/sdo.cpp:352:1: error: unknown type
      name 'function_entry'
function_entry sdo_exception_methods[] = {
^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
15 warnings and 20 errors generated.
```

Any ideas on why this will not compile?

Answer (score 0):

Replacing "function_entry" with "zend_function_entry" was enough for a simple test which I ran on OS X 10.9.5 with PHP 5.4.30 using the code published here: http://php.webtutor.pl/en/2011/07/07/how-to-create-php-extensions-in-c-part-i-adding-simple-function/

Comments on https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61479 also recommend replacing "pval" with "zval" in the source code, but if you're using complex data types in your extension then the whole story there is probably a bit more complicated.